# MySQL ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table is full - only for specific values

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a row to an InnoDB table using simple `INESRT` query. For some values I get an error, while for others the query is accepted:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO pylog (id, description) VALUES ('606_0', 'testing');
ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table 'pylog' is full

mysql> INSERT INTO pylog (id, description) VALUES ('706_0', 'testing');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO pylog (id, description) VALUES ('610_0', 'testing');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO pylog (id, description) VALUES ('609_0', 'testing');
ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table 'pylog' is full

mysql> INSERT INTO pylog (id, description) VALUES ('609_01', 'testing');
ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table 'pylog' is full

mysql> INSERT INTO pylog (id, description) VALUES ('610_01', 'testing');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

The table was created with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE pylog (
    id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ctime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    description TEXT
);
```

The table already contains 63,954 rows, which were created by a python script using MySQLdb module. The DB takes ~2GB and the disk has ~20GB of free space. Only recently I encountered this problem, both when I run my python script and when I run the query directly from mysql.

The code I run:

```
# CONN is the connection, CUR is the cursor
if not CUR or not CONN:
    return

# Create an ID for the new row, in the format '{:d}_{:09d}'
CUR.execute('SELECT id FROM pylog WHERE id LIKE "{}\_%" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1'.format(MACHINE_ID))
if CUR.rowcount > 0:
    last_id = CUR.fetchone()[0]
    count = int(last_id.split('_')[-1]) + 1
else:
    count = 0
log_id = '{}_{:09d}'.format(MACHINE_ID, count)
CUR.execute('INSERT INTO pylog (id, description) VALUES (%s,%s)', (log_id, text))
CONN.commit()
```

Why do I get "The table is full" error only for some values, while obviously the table is not full?

Comment: DId you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/full-table.html and the linked https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html ?

Comment: What Operating System are you using? And what format is the file system (FAT32? NTFS?).  As @Nanne linked - you may have hit an OS limit on file size (2GB is common).

Comment: Do you have any side effects in place for this table like triggers which try to fill other tables (which fail) or do you delete rows from this table while adding new rows (so the space become available for a short time and the insert query succeed)?

Comment: @Nanne I checked these links, didn't find a solution there. Note that in some cases the INSERT query is accepted, which implies that it is not a problem of disk space or table configuration.

Comment: @GregHNZ I'm running Linux Debian 8.6, the file system is ext4.

Comment: @Progman I have no triggers or table relations.
However I do encounter the same problem in other tables as well, if I skip over this query.

Comment: Might be worth running a `check table`. Read up first - implications for innodb looked like repair consists of dumping and reloading the data. Mi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the maximum size for your innodb_data_file_path in your my.cnf configuration file is too low. Can you try:

```
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:512M
```

Comment: Apparently one table being full affected other tables as well. This solved it. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like autoextend should prevent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your LAMP stack uses XAMPP for management, click the **config** button on the **MySQL** row and next to the **Admin** button.

This will open up the config file.

There, do a 'Ctrl + F' for *innodb_data_file_path* and update the **max** value to something higher and restart your MySQL server.

It should work now.